# Im Why does the MIME type changes to text/html when I extend my route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**PROBLEM:** So I am developing an express web app. And I have a cart page which my customers can access, through route 'root url/customers/orders'. And when I try to access that route, the css file and the js file doesn't work. I.e styles from css file doesn't work, and the js file too doesn't work. Because both their content-type on the request header is 'text/html'.

I hadn't encountered this problem when all my routes had extended one step form the root url, like 'root url/login' or 'root url/register' or 'root url/customers', everything works fine. But when I extend these routes, like 'root url/customers/orders', then I am slapped in the face by this problem.
Can anyone help me and why exactly is this happening?

The route that I'm using to render this particular page:

```
app.get('/customers/orders', auth, orderController().index);
```

*PS* The auth is a middleware to make sure the user is logged in.

The 'orderController' :

```
function orderController () {
return {
    async index(req, res){
      try{
        const orders = await Order.find({customer : 
        req.user._id}).populate('customer').sort({'createdAt' : -1});
        res.render('Customers/Order', {
          title : "Your orders-Pizza",
          orders : orders,
          moment : moment,
      });
    } catch (err) {
          if(err) {
            req.flash('error', 'Sorry something went wrong. Try again.');
            return res.redirect('/order');
          }
        }
    },

   }
  }
}
```

**Edit after realizing my mistake**
Here was my code for serving static files(this was where I had made the mistake):

```
app.use(express.static('./public'));
```

Here I haven't used '/' after public, right? So what I should have done when linking my css file(or any other static file), is included '/' before the file name like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/css.css">
```

And the js file:

```
<script src="/js/js.js" defer></script>
```

And voila!, everything works fine.

**Conclusion**
You have to include a '/' before a file name(or folder if you have the file inside one).

Comment: Your express routing code,  without seeing any code it's really hard for us to see were you have gone wrong. :(  If there is lots of code, you should try a create a minimal verifiable example of the issue.

Comment: I'm really new to this whole stack overflow thing. So I don't know how to work stuffs here. But there I've included the codes. Hope it helps you find something.

Comment: Remember if you render a route like -> `/customers/orders` and you have a link in your html like `main.css`, your browser is going to look for a file called `/customers/orders/main.css`,  I assume your static assets are not there?.   To get around this use none relative pathnames for static assets eg.. `/assests/main.css`,  etc.

Comment: Im using the /assets/main.css way to fetch my static files. And, no it's not a 404 error. The files are sent to the client, its just that the browser doesn't want to apply styles from that file due to incorrect MIME type.

Comment: Still really not enough detail here to help, one idea is that one of your middleware's is messing up the headers.

Comment: @keith I figured it out. More like, I hit-and-trialed it out. See the edited post above. And thank you, your comments did help me. Express.static is, I guess, more powerful than I thought. Apparantly, it is responsible for setting the content-type of the static files. Gotta look more into it. Thanks!